# How to write out or trace specific commands in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

In a PowerShell script that I'm creating, I want to output specific commands with the parameter values being passed. The output could go to a log file and/or the console output. The following will output what I want to the console but I have to duplicate the line of script of interest and at some point a subtle mistake will be made where the commands don't match. I've tried `Set-PSDebug` and `Trace-Command` and neither give the result I seek. I've thought about putting the line of script into a string, writing it out, and then calling `Invoke-Expression` but I'll give up autocompletion/intellisense.

Example with duplicated line for writing and execution:

```
Write-Output "New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $rgFullName -Location $location -Tag $tags -Force"
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $rgFullName -Location $location -Tag $tags -Force
```

Output result with expanded variables. $tags didn't expand to actual hashtable values:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name StorageAccounts -Location West US -Tag System.Collections.Hashtable -Force
```

What other options or commandlets can I use to achieve the tracing without writing duplicated code and maybe even expanding the hashtable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in feature I'm aware of that echoes a version of a command being executed with variables and expressions used in arguments *expanded*.

Even if there were, it would only work *faithfully* in simple cases, because not all objects have *literal* representations.

However, with limitations, you can roll your own solution, based on `&`, the call [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators), and [parameter splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) via a hashtable of argument values defined up front:

```
# Sample argument values.
$rgFullName = 'full name'
$location = 'loc'
$tags = @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 }

# Define the command to execute:
#   * as a string variable that contains the command name / path
#   * as a hashtable that defines the arguments to pass via
#     splatting (see below.)
$command = 'New-AzureRmResourceGroup'
$commandArgs = [ordered] @{
  Name = $rgFullName
  Location = $location
  Tag = $tags
  Force = $True
}

# Echo the command to be executed.
$command, $commandArgs

# Execute the command, using & and splatting (note the '@' instead of '$')
& $command @commandArgs
```

The above echoes the following (excluding any output from the actual execution):

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroup

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Name                           full name
Location                       loc
Tag                            {two, three, one}
Force                          True
```

As you can see:

- PowerShell's default output formatting results in a multi-line representation of the hashtable used for splatting.
- The `$tags` entry, a hashtable itself, is unfortunately only represented by its *keys* - the values are missing.

---

However, you can **customize the output *programmatically*** to **create a single-line representation that *approximates* the command with expanded arguments**, including showing hashtables with their values, using **helper function `convertTo-PseudoCommandLine`**:

```
# Helper function that converts a command name and its arguments specified
# via a hashtable or array into a pseudo-command line string that 
# *approximates* the command using literal values.
# Main use is for logging, to reflect commands with their expanded arguments.
function convertTo-PseudoCommandLine ($commandName, $commandArgs) {

  # Helper script block that transforms a single parameter-name/value pair
  # into part of a command line.
  $sbToCmdLineArg = { param($paramName, $arg) 
    $argTransformed = ''; $sep = ' '
    if ($arg -is [Collections.IDictionary]) { # hashtable
      $argTransformed = '@{{{0}}}' -f ($(foreach ($key in $arg.Keys) { '{0}={1}' -f (& $sbToCmdLineArg '' $key), (& $sbToCmdLineArg '' $arg[$key]) }) -join ';')
    } elseif ($arg -is [Collections.ICollection]) { # array / collection
      $argTransformed = $(foreach ($el in $arg) { & $sbToCmdLineArg $el }) -join ','
    }
    elseif ($arg -is [bool]) { # assume it is a switch
      $argTransformed = ('$False', '$True')[$arg]
      $sep = ':' # passing an argument to a switch requires -switch:<val> format
    } elseif ($arg -match '^[$@(]|\s|"') {
      $argTransformed = "'{0}'" -f ($arg -replace "'", "''") # single-quote and escape embedded single quotes
    } else {
      $argTransformed = "$arg" # stringify as is - no quoting needed
    }
    if ($paramName) { # a parameter-argument pair
      '-{0}{1}{2}' -f $paramName, $sep, $argTransformed
    } else { # the command name or a hashtable key or value
      $argTransformed
    }
  }

  # Synthesize and output the pseudo-command line.
  $cmdLine = (& $sbToCmdLineArg '' $commandName)
  if ($commandArgs -is [Collections.IDictionary]) { # hashtable
    $cmdLine += ' ' + 
      $(foreach ($param in $commandArgs.Keys) { & $sbToCmdLineArg $param $commandArgs[$param] }) -join ' '
  } elseif ($commandArgs) { # array / other collection
    $cmdLine += ' ' + 
      $(foreach ($arg in $commandArgs) { & $sbToCmdLineArg '' $arg }) -join ' '
  }

  # Output the command line.
  # If the comamnd name ended up quoted, we must prepend '& '
  if ($cmdLine[0] -eq "'") {
    "& $cmdLine"
  } else {
    $cmdLine
  }

}
```

With `convertTo-PseudoCommandLine` defined (*before or above* the code below), you can then use:

```
# Sample argument values.
$rgFullName = 'full name'
$location = 'loc'
$tags = @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 }

# Define the command to execute:
#   * as a string variable that contains the command name / path
#   * as a hashtable that defines the arguments to pass via
#     splatting (see below.)
$command = 'New-AzureRmResourceGroup'
$commandArgs = [ordered] @{
  Name = $rgFullName
  Location = $location
  Tag = $tags
  Force = $True
}


# Echo the command to be executed as a pseud-command line
# created by the helper function.
convertTo-PseudoCommandLine $command $commandArgs

# Execute the command, using & and splatting (note the '@' instead of '$')
& $command @commandArgs
```

This yields (excluding any output from the actual execution):

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name 'full name' -Location loc -Tag @{two=2;three=3;one=1} -Force:$True
```